# How do I use the break after the item is added?

Tags: javascript

If the items in the itemsSold array in the customer's product are null, I want to add the 'car' element and exit the loop with break.

```js
let customer = [{
    active: true,
    product: {
      itemSold: [null, null],
      purchasedItems: []
    },
  },
  {
    active: true,
    product: {
      itemSold: [null, null],
      purchasedItems: []
    },
  },
];

let itemSold = ["car", "home"];
let purchasedItems = ["phone", "computer"];

for (let i = 0; i < customer.length; i++) {
  //What should i write?
  if (customer[i].product["itemSold"] === null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Some of your code doesn't make sense - why put `this` in front of customer in the loop, and where did `passengers` come from? `itemSold` is also an array so doing a check with `=== null` will never be true.

Comment: `itemSold.every(item => item === null)`

Comment: I fixed it. Elements inside are placeholders. for this reason, it should break the loop before it is added to other customers.